# Php обернуть весь текст в html в тэг?

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Как можно во всей html странице через *simple html dom* можно обернуть весь текст в тэгах, в тэг допустим `<var>` ?

То есть к примеру

`<div>text text<span>texttext</span><h1>text</h1></div>`

должно превратиться в

`<div><var>text text</var><span><var>texttext</var></span><h1><var>text</var></h1></div>`

Comment: любопытное вы конечно хотите ... А что если `<div> text <span> text2 </span> test3 </div>` как оно должно быть обернуто

Comment: 3 штуки var на каждый текст соответственно)

Comment: `preg_replace('/(?:\s*<.*?>)+\s*\K([^<]*)(?!$)/s',"<var>$1</var>",$html);` делает то же самое, если что ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете найти все текстовые элементы.

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_find

```
// Find all text blocks
$es = $html->find('text');
```

А затем попробуйте для каждого делать:

```
$e->outertext = "<var>" . $e->innertext . "</var>";
```

Рабочий пример:

```
$html = str_get_html('<html><body>Hello!</body>It works.</html>');
foreach($html->find('text') as $e) {
    $e->outertext = "<var>" . $e->innertext . "</var>";    
}

echo $html->save();
```

Проверено на http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/

Comment: пробовал, очень много пустых тэгов при переносах строки в коде, можно ли это как то пофиксить?

Comment: @SdafsFasafs Так проверяйте свои тексты что они содержат видимые символы. И кстати очень интересно, что произойдет когда вы содержимое тегов <script> завернете. И кстати, почему именно simpleHTML, можно же проще ...

Comment: @SdafsFasafs `if(trim($e->innertext) != "") ...`

Comment: @TarwirdurTuron, подскажи пожалуйста как потом эти тэги удалить не трогая содержимого? Пробую     foreach($body->find('var') as $e) {
    $e->outertext = '';  
    $e->innertext = $e->innertext;
    } но не выходит

Comment: @SdafsFasafs `foreach($html->find('var') as $e) {$e->outertext = $e->plaintext;}`

Comment: Может лучше использовать `{$e->outertext = $e->innertext;}`, если оригинальная строка содержала тег `<var>`. Тем не менее совсем не понятно, зачем вообще так делать.